# From a game design point of view, what are the implications of using realistic distances in an open world map?

Tags: game-design, maps, scale

I'm starting an open world game and the plan is to have a single "open world" map that should contain a medieval citadel (1.4 km/2 - taking as example Palmanova in Italy) and some countryside around it.

The plan is to delimit the map with a river and some hills.

What I realized so far is that most open-world games take a specific approach when it comes to size their areas, it's unlikely you'll ever find a realistically sized citadel, they will tend to be all pretty small, and it will take no more than a few minutes to run from one side to the other of it.

An example that comes to mind is The Witcher 3, the Novigrad/Velen map is 15.2 km2 but the city is approx 0.25km2, which is a lot smaller than what I plan to build for my map.

To walk from one side to the other of my citadel the player should take around 15 minutes (according to Google Maps), while, as I said, in most games you can run through a city in a matter of 1 or 2 minutes.

Keep in mind there will be no vehicles and I'd still like to have the countryside take most of the map area to keep everything proportioned and realistic.

The question is, is it a good idea to build such a "large" citadel? What gameplay issues could I face? How should I handle the fact that the countryside will end up being extremely huge (and empty?) if I want to keep it properly proportioned with the citadel?

Comment: Do you need your players to be able to run across the whole citadel in 2 minutes, or in 15 minutes? What does your game need?

Comment: I don't think the time it takes to cross the citadel would be a huge problem, I'd like to let them spend a lot of time in it doing quests and such. The problem I see is that if I make the citadel so large I'll need to proportionally size the rest of the map/countryside and that will end up being huge.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, keep in mind that they likely had horses back then. Ubisoft games tend to have the players unlock "fast travel" locations by having them go there by foot first, so even if you have a large map, and you realize that it's too big for players to travel by foot, you could add those fast travel stable locations, and have them unlocked via quests.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm unsure though about the map balance, I would have an highly dense area and then this sterminate countryside where I can for sure scatter some buildings and such around but still would feel pretty empty I suppose. If big AAA games can't fill huge maps I doubt we could do better. An alternative I can think of would be a Outriders approach, where the walkable area is actually limited by pre-made "paths".

Comment: It sounds like you understand the drawback here: getting from point A to B (eg. from wherever you are to your next objective) takes a long time. And it sounds like you've considered that drawback and concluded it's not a major problem for your game's goals and style of play. What are you hoping that a stranger who does not know your game would be able to tell you in an answer to this post?

Comment: @FezVrasta: The problem is not that AAA can't fill huge maps. The problem is that traversing a huge map is _boring_

Comment: Assassins Creed Odyssey has a very huge (albeit not realistic) map of Greece. But when you play it, almost all that is not purposely designed locations (important cities etc) is just  fields with copy-pasted enemy outposts. And its not even real size! Also, try to go out in wherever you live and walk 15 minutes in one direction, and count how many interesting thing you see. In most places in the world, none.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Maybe it's a game about going out to buy a burger, or groceries. I wonder if anyone's made that game before. No surprises, no enemies, no skills. You just walk for 15 minutes, give the cashier your money, get the thing, walk back for 15 minutes, and then reflect on what it really means to be a video game. Includes 60 seconds waiting for a traffic light.

Comment: "try to go out in wherever you live and walk 15 minutes in one direction, and count how many interesting thing you see. In most places in the world, none" — that implies quite a narrow definition of "interesting thing". For example, [in a handful of soil, there are more bacteria than there are people on earth, and we have no idea what 99% of them do](https://www.soilassociation.org/causes-campaigns/save-our-soil/10-soil-facts/).

Comment: @FezVrasta A suggestion: Download one of those realistically-sized minecraft city maps you can find online. There are a bunch of them, in several flavors. Load one up and walk around the city to see if that's the feel you want for you player. There is a famous Minas Tirith minecraft map that is _mind boggling_ in terms of scale and complexity.

Comment: One possible implication is that your game will end up tagged on Steam as a "Walking Simulator".  Though, to be fair, there are quite a few solid games tagged that way.

Comment: Medieval citadels were not nearly that big.  Most castles were designed to be defensible by garrisons of 20-100 men and were rarely more than 200-300m across.  Even major fortified cities like London had walled off urban areas less than 1 km^2 with most of the "city" actually being the rural farmlands sprawling off in every direction.  Palmanova was built well after the medieval period; so, unless you are aiming at a late Renaissance setting (AKA: not medieval), the size of things in the Witcher 3 are actually more historically accurate than you have in mind.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm reminded of commentary around that Warhammer Fantasy MMO where you'd spend hours just walking between towns...

Comment: @Nosajimiki my game is actually set in modern days, sorry if I referenced the wrong historical period for Palmanova. The idea is to let the players play in this citadel in a kind of post-apocalyptic setting where existing fortified cities have been repurposed.

Comment: One consideration is if your game's day/night cycle is shortened. In Final Fantasy XV's open world, driving your car, it can take one hour of in-game time to travel five miles of in-game distance.

Comment: I never played it extensively but this reminds me of World of Warcraft's launch. It was basically a walking simulator with nothing intrinsically interesting anywhere you go. I think I made it to level 10 and decided I had enough simulated walking to last me a lifetime. It was just too much "meh" for what is apparently a good game considering its longevity.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Almost no game uses realistically scaled maps for cities. The problem with creating cities which are even close to the size of real cities is:

- Maps become difficult for the player to navigate. They can easily get lost.
- It is very hard to make all of that content interesting. Creating a large amount of good content is time-consuming and draining. So when you want to create a huge city while you are on a budget, you have to cut a lot of corners. That means resorting to lots of copy&paste environments and procedural generation. The result will be a game which is "as wide as an ocean, but as shallow as a puddle". Lots of environment to explore, but it takes too long to find anything interesting in it.
- Maps take a very long time to traverse. Traversal might be interesting if it happens in a new and interesting environment (see last point), but when it happens in an environment the player has already explored, or which isn't that interesting to explore in the first place, then it turns into a tedious chore. The player will wish that points of interest were closer together, so they can spend less time walking and more time enjoying actual gameplay.
- And then there are of course technological challenges. Having all that data for a seamless city without loading screens requires advanced techniques for rendering and simulation. The larger the world, the deeper you have to reach into your bag of tricks to make sure you stay within the resource constraints of your target platform.

  And no, Unreal Engine 5 with its new [automatic LOD system](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/RenderingFeatures/Nanite/) and [world partitioning](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/WorldFeatures/WorldPartition/) will *not* magically solve all your problems. When you use them in practice, you will see that they do have limitations, problems and quirks of their own you need to work around. In the worst case, you might find out that they aren't suitable for the unique technical challenges you face in your game and you will have to roll your own solution anyway. Also, LOD and environment loading are just two problems of many. There will still be plenty of your own systems which you need to adapt to work despite constant loading and unloading of world content and which are going to run into resource constraints when you try to simulate them in the whole world at once.

In conclusion: **Quality is more important than quantity!** It's better to have a smaller game world which is tightly packed with creative, unique and interesting content than a larger game world which is boring and bland.

I am looking forward to exploring the world of your game.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I feel like I should focus on the citadel and block the access to the countryside all together, it's going to be more manageable and allow us to focus on the important parts.

Comment: Probably a good example would be WoW's large cities. Moving around was a chore if you were based in one of the capitals while leveling.

Comment: For Fallout 3 & 4, they deliberately made the buildings smaller on the outside than the inside, to make it less tedious to walk past a building. The city of Washington was likewise much bigger to walk through than to walk around. Sometimes fun is more important than realism.

Comment: @Robyn fun is *always* more important than realism unless you are making a military war simulator! But sometimes realism adds its own fun so don't discount that.

Comment: A good example of a "quality over quantity" game might be something like Zelda: Ocarina of Time. Except for the water temple, pretty much everything in the game is there for a reason. The things that feel like they don't have a reason either get one later, or they're hints for newbies that you never visit because you already know the information. There's a lot of going back to the same areas in different contexts. The NPCs that make the village feel populated? Most of them tell you something about your quest even if you don't understand it yet. And so on. (actually a few of them are useless)

Comment: On the remark about loading times: The ubiquity of fast storage like SSDs and recent evolutions in GPUs being able to directly access SSD storage like in modern consoles and the upcoming Windows 11 release means that it's becoming more and more technically feasible to have a large map without many loading zones. In addition, there was already tech in the PS2 era that gave the perception of a zone without loading times by hiding these loading times behind doors and in engine cutscenes.

Comment: @Nzall You are not wrong, but storage speed is not the only limiting factor here. The problem is that you still have a limited amount of system RAM and GPU RAM. So you need a strategy for when to load and unload which resources and what to do if a resource is still not available when you need it. And then there is the question of which background simulations you run when and where in what level of detail (traffic, pedestrians, physics...). All of this is anything but trivial.

Comment: and the tv trope covering it: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThrivingGhostTown

Comment: I vaguely remember an article about the development of Witcher 3 that described that they aimed for the player to come accross something of interest every 9 seconds or something similarly crazy.

Comment: @Robyn https://youtu.be/S6uGx7kf4Ng?t=40

Comment: @Nzall As I understand it, the direct-to-SSD thing is about pretending to load more data than fits in memory, by unloading it as soon as it's offscreen and reloading it as soon as the player turns around. You still have all the complexity of loading, you get to do it with a finer grain. But even with an HDD you can still do "streaming levels", you just have to load stuff further in advance of the player getting there. Minecraft does large maps just fine, even on HDDs in 2010.

Comment: @user253751 for my project I'm using UE5 so I get to use for free Nanite and the level streaming system it provides, loading huge worlds is a non-issue.

Comment: Also I can't imagine **why** someone would want to hold so much data in memory that they can't afford to store the part behind the player. A whole 4k frame is only 32MB of RAM. They have gigabytes.

Comment: The Witness is another good "quality over quantity" example. Feels big, and every part has stuff in it.

Comment: There is one category of games that uses a realistic scaled world - flight simulators.  Not just the training ones, but even the consumer-level entertainment ones.  Now you generally can't *interact* with most of this world (in fact most interactions with the world in a flight sim are a *very bad thing*.)  But they do generally represent distances accurately, for what it's worth.

Comment: The technology of "walking a full city" isn't that challenging anymore. We have algorithms and methods to do it, "good enough" on low-end systems, and with essentially full-screen-resolution on high end systems (see the Unreal Engine 5 Nanite demos!)

The comment about "content is hard" and "quality rules" are spot on, though!

Comment: @JonWatte Sure, what Unreal Engine 5 does is impressive, but it's not the golden hammer which solves *all* the problems with large game worlds. I added another paragraph to the answer.

Comment: A great example of "Wide as an ocean, but shallow as a puddle" is Elite Dangerous.  Their are 4 billion planets and they are all huge, I think to scale.  But they are all boring rocks, with seemingly no difference except terrain height.  (It may be better since odyssey, don't know).  Outer Wilds on the other hand, only has like 6 planets which are *really* small, but they're all a joy to explore.

Comment: @Philipp I'm not saying that you don't need to do work. But we did walkable streaming cities on an Earth-scale globe 15 years ago. Google Earth does something similar (although it has less 3D to it.) It's totally technically doable, with work. But it's not "so hard you can't make a game on top of it." That bit is solved, if you wanted to. The reason we don't do it, is just like you say: that it's impossible to make all that content captivating and interesting!

Answer (score 8):

You've already removed the main negative of a 1:1 scale map by focusing it on a small area instead of an entire city or countryside, but a citadel is still on the large side. The biggest issue here is travel time. Basically, if I want to walk to the store in real life, it might take me 12 minutes (from Google maps). That's alright; a little longer than I might like, but only because I'm carrying groceries. In a game, if I get a quest to go to the store, and it's going to take 12 minutes just to get there, that's completely unacceptable. Games shouldn't waste the player's time getting to the gameplay.

So, here's how to cheat. Aside from the obvious solution of changing the scale, you can also change the walking/running speed, have rapid transportation options, cluster useful locations together, and not have quests that require the player to cross the map. For a citadel, I'd make large portions of it simply not relevant to gameplay. (A lot of the north-east portion burned down in a fire and hasn't been rebuilt. The south-east portion is gated mansions that are only accessible in one quest where you don't get to explore, etc.) I would also make a citadel that's significantly below average in size. (This is different from changing the scale in that it's still 1:1 scale, just using a smaller space as a base.)

Comment: Or: Make travel gameplay. GTA, spider-man, just to name a few.

Answer (score 2):

### It works if you treat most of the citadel as part of your world map

I remember an MMO I played a while back (can't remember which one) that got away with this just fine because about half the quests were actually inside the main city.  So instead of a small city that you are constantly leaving and coming back to; the city itself was the quest space, and only small sections of the city were clusters of shops that made up elements of the game you would traditionally define as "the city" from a gameplay perspective.

The city was divided up into 3-4 sections; so, as a low level you would be in the residential section using a cluster of mom-and-pop stores as your home base area and going off to do quests taking down gangs and breaking into someone's home to steal something, etc. in all of the surrounding areas of the city.  Then as you got higher level you would move on to the docks section of the city where there was a better small cluster of businesses, and tougher missions; so, on and so forth.  This was basically the same experience as moving to a new home city you often find in games. From what I recall, you did not actually have very many quests outside of the city until you were about a lvl 20; so, while the city was the size of the world maps used in some games, it was okay because the city itself was treated as a the world map.

So taking 15 minute to walk from one side of the citadel to the other is not a deal breaker at all as long as you have enough things to do along the way.  As long as you are never spending more than 1-2 minutes to get from one Point of Interest to the next, how big the citadel is is not important.

Comment: Now that I think about that, the original Guild Wars Nightfall map used the same approach, there was a very large urban area, but the shops where focused in some defined squares.

Comment: @FezVrasta You mean Factions, surely?

Comment: Yeah, probably, it's been a while since I played them :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think most players really think in forms of scale when traversing a world. It's more about interesting stuff relative to times spend.

If your player has to run for 2 minutes between to interesting points, they'll be bored for 2 minutes. The world may feel vast, but the boredom will make this a negative.

So, how can you work around that?

- You could make your game about free-running or other traversal. Make
  the getting from A to B a challenge. The better the player is the
  faster he gets there, or the more points he collects on the way.
- Spread smaller points of interest in between those points.
  Collectathons are an entire genre build upon the idea of spreading
  small things to collect between actual interesting points. But you're not limited to collectibles. It could also be NPCs to talk with, or enemies to fight.
- Fast travel. If you don't want vehicles you could just have the player select the point of interest on a map and teleport him there. But then you have to ask yourself how the player unlocks the fast travel points. Get there once? Gets it from a quest? Scanning/binoculars minigame? A good fast travel system completely negates the need for a city between the points, though.

But those don't really solve your issue, I think. You should not do something in a game because "it's realistic". If players want realism they don't play games. Instead you should think about what purpose a vast region serves the player/gameplay.

- Are there animals roaming the area to hunt?
- Are there treasures hidden?
- Is it a big sandbox with NPCs the player can interact with, and/or quests take place?
- Houses to rob?
- Are there some sick ramps and rails to skate on?
- Is the player a giant robot and the city will have some really nice effects when he tumbles through it fighting a Kaiju?

Answer (score 0):

When you start modelling, is easy to think that using realistic distances to normalize your world with will be awesome!
However the first problem comes with the insane amount of detail real life has, and then, how boring moving in real life really is. Maybe the reason why people play games, instead of going "out there"?

However, when you are making your own world, you usually change the scale to somewhat that makes sense. For me, that happened to be 3.5 M as the minimal sphere, streets are 14 M, including 2 lanes, and opposite sidewalks. This kind of dimensions "make sense" when you look through the game camera...

The other thing you need to keep in mind is to minimize the max distance at which opposite objects can be. You calculate this with the mesh density: if too high, FPS will take a dive down, if its too low, the content may be a little stale.

But the most important is: you put what you need in your Citadel, and if you don't need it, you don't put it. Maybe there is no direct path between one side of the Citadel to the other? Perhaps you need to choose going into the Market, which will add ten minutes to traverse? Or maybe the other route is through the mud pit, which may present you with a terminal encounter of the wrong kind?

Answer (score 0):

Another point that I don't see in any of the answers: in some engines you will start to run into numerical precision issues when using very large maps.

For example, the Unity engine uses the 32-bit `float` type for all floating-point engine functions, such as position. At large distances from the world origin, the precision limitations of a 32-bit float start to cause glitches such as jittery movement. I've also seen some visual effects (e.g. ambient occlusion) glitch out at similar distances.

The Unity Editor displays a precision warning when any object is further than 100km from the world origin on any axis. This means that the maximum safe playable area is `200km x 200km = 40,000km`. That's much bigger than what you'd find in a typical first-person or third-person game, but can potentially be an issue in endless open-world games (e.g. Minecraft), flight simulators, naval simulations, etc.

Comment: This limitation can be over come quite easily with cleaver instancing. If your game engine can't support a single environment more than 200km, you just break up your world into smaller maps.  So, if you for example have a world with a bunch of 50-100km islands, you can make it so that as the player is out in deep sea with nothing much to look at that he does not realize that he's just been moved from the left side of one map, to a loading screen that looks like being in the middle of the ocean, to the right side of the next map.

Comment: @Nosajimiki That is possible but I would not characterize it as "quite easy". It requires very careful planning of your world design and adds new technical challenges; for example, ensuring that the engine doesn't stutter during the transition and everything (even the waves of a procedural ocean) is lined up after the transition.

Answer (score -1):

GTA, Cyberpunk and other similar open world games have city maps of mostly correct scale. MSFS has a kind of realistic world map. The key - these games didn't require devs to build every single house and players to walk all those distances.

For travel, first option would be to limit players to certain zones, making full map size irrelevant. While this is a huge citadel, you are in outer ring of defenses in chapters 1 and 2, travelling around in a circle or something, trying to get suitable clothes to be allowed inside. Then you get nice clothes and reach inner parts ... but all your newfound wealth makes you a target in outer areas. There is still a long 10 minute walk from one side to the other but you would do that walk just once - while you are fleeing the citadel after killing the noble, rest of the time would be spent in smaller areas you can traverse easily.

To keep world open and especially when you get to the countryside you might want to ditch the "no vehicles" policy and use carriages, magic portals/maps and similar that get you from point A to point B (nearly) instantly. This takes out some exploring, but you might give players these options only later to preserve initial mystery yet not bore them to death in later stages of the game. For example they might require suitable clothes to get in a carriage - initial beggar won't be allowed to ride one. Or they need to find the magic map, or the wizards created/allowed magic portals later. Or whatever else fits.

As for countryside, it will be and it should be boring if you are making something realistic. Yeah, this is an endless field of wheat, what else would it be? From inside the citadel it would look like uniform "field" texture with "forest" texture in the next part etc - as if you were building a view from citadel that doesn't let you walk in those fields. While players could explore these fields and forests in detail, few would. A quest or two along "interrogate farmer", "catch that wolf", "fight bandits that blocked the road through the forest" or "notice path through the field and investigate where does it lead" are mostly all things you would realistically do there. You obviously need to get to those quests by faster means than walking for an hour to reach the bandit ambush in the forest.

Even if 95%+ of the map is "boring areas", this isn't a problem by itself. Our real maps are mostly "boring areas" too. Just make sure that you don't require players to spend any significant amount of time there, and don't spend any significant amount of time on them yourself either. As a simple rule, amount of time you spend building an area should be proportional to player time spent in an area. But this doesn't restrict size of the area.

Comment: GTA map scales are still far from reality. The [city of GTA V](https://www.igta5.com/images/collectibles-map.jpg) is loosely based on [real-world Los Angeles](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.9380132,-118.03217,72126m/data=!3m1!1e3). Just compare the scale of those two maps by counting the number of city blocks between the harbor in the south and the mountain range in the north.

Comment: And the argument "the real world has lots of boring spaces, so game worlds should have lots of boring spaces too" is a very bad game design philosophy. Reality is only a valuable guide to game design as long as it makes the game more accessible or more interesting. As soon as it stops providing that service, it's time to take breaks from reality and start to think like a game designer, not a simulation designer.

Comment: I think 95%+ of the map being boring is indeed a problem. You have lots of content that you don't even want the player to bother with drawing computing resources and player attention. Players will inevitably wind up in the boring zones on purpose or by accident, and will be frustrated when they do. Purposefully building most of the map to be unsuitable for player use seems at best pointless and at worst counterproductive.

Comment: If you could have a 100% interesting real-life-sized map that would indeed be pretty cool, but you can't. It would also be a lot of wasted effort. Have you even explored the whole city you live in? On the other hand, players would be able to share interesting locations with each other.

Comment: @user253751: Bard's Tale has hundreds of buildings in the map, almost all of which can be entered, but entering vast majority of nondescript buildings them will simply call up an "empty building" screen.  There are a few nondescript buildings which have surprises in them, which could perhaps be found by grinding, but could be better found by employing in-game or real-world rumors.